# PowerShell's Get-Member cmdlet doesn't report all methods

Tags: powershell

```
notepad
$Notepad = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Process -Filter "Name = 'notepad.exe'"
Invoke-CimMethod -InputObject $Notepad -MethodName Terminate
```

These statements work correctly, but when I use `Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Process -Filter "Name = 'notepad.exe'" | get-member -force` to find the `Terminate` method, it doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[JosefZ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39842761/45375) is helpful and offers an effective solution; let me complement it with a different way of explaining the issue:

**tl;dr:**

To **discover the methods** supported by a CIM instance via an object returned by [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance), access its `.CimClass.CimClassMethods` property:

```bash
PS> (Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "Name = 'notepad.exe'").CimClass.CimClassMethods

Name                    ReturnType Parameters                                                            Qualifiers
----                    ---------- ----------                                                            ----------
Create                      UInt32 {CommandLine, CurrentDirectory, ProcessStartupInformation, ProcessId} {Constructor, Implemented, MappingStrings, Privileges...}
Terminate                   UInt32 {Reason}                                                              {Destructor, Implemented, MappingStrings, Privileges...}
GetOwner                    UInt32 {Domain, User}                                                        {Implemented, MappingStrings, ValueMap}
GetOwnerSid                 UInt32 {Sid}                                                                 {Implemented, MappingStrings, ValueMap}
SetPriority                 UInt32 {Priority}                                                            {Implemented, MappingStrings, ValueMap}
AttachDebugger              UInt32 {}                                                                    {Implemented, ValueMap}
GetAvailableVirtualSize     UInt32 {AvailableVirtualSize}
```

To restrict the above to *instance* methods:

```bash
(Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "Name = 'notepad.exe'").CimClass.CimClassMethods | 
  Where-Object { -not $_.Qualifiers['Static'] }
```

Alternatively, pass the name of a CIM *class* to [`Get-CimClass`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-cimclass), as in JosefZ's answer, in which case accessing `.CimClassMethods` on the output object is sufficient.

***Invoking* CIM methods requires a dedicated cmdlet, [`Invoke-CimMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/invoke-cimmethod)**, for the reasons explained below; passing *arguments* requires passing a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) (dictionary) of *parameter-name value pairs* to the `-Arguments` parameter; see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77388551/45375) for details and an example.

---

It is reasonable to expect objects returned from cmdlets to reveal all their members when piped to `Get-Member` - that's how it *generally* works in PowerShell.
**However, dealing with [CIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Information_Model_(computing)) entities (classes and instances) is a special case:**

- **PowerShell** and its .NET-based type (class) system on the one hand, and **the [platform-neutral CIM standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Information_Model_(computing))**, modeling (typically) remote computing resources on the other, are **distinct worlds**, with their own entities, that map imperfectly onto each other.
- **CIM instances are *partially* mapped onto PowerShell objects of type `[Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance]`, as returned by `Get-CimInstance`**:

  - These PowerShell objects are in effect ***partial, read-only snapshots* of the underlying CIM instances**.

    - By default, the full set of *properties* of the underlying CIM instance is represented on the PowerShell object.
      Note: While *technically* writeable properties are returned as well (e.g., the `State` property of a `Win32_Service` instance), *assigning* to such a property seems to be *ignored* in practice.
    - However, no *methods* of the underlying CIM class are present (presumably, because  methods are usually used to *modify* objects, and thus not needed for a read-only representation).
  - You cannot directly *modify* CIM instances through their local `[Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance]` representations - **dedicated cmdlets are required to *modify* CIM instances**: `Invoke-CimMethod` to *invoke methods*, and `Set-CimInstance` to *set properties*.
  - Similarly, **you cannot directly discover all members of a CIM class/instance by inspecting `[Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance]` objects with `Get-Member`**, given that they are only a *partial* representation of their underlying CIM instances.
    As stated at the top, you have two options:

    - Access a given `[Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance]` object's `CimClass` property, which PowerShell automatically adds.
    - Call `Get-CimClass -ClassName <CimClassName>`.
    - Both methods return a `[Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimClass]` instance that describes the CIM class in terms of its properties and methods, among other things, but note that this introspection information is based on *CIM* rules.

Answer (score 7):

The [Invoke-CimMethod](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj590759.aspx) cmdlet invokes a method of a Common Information Model (CIM) class or **CIM instance** …

The [Get-CimInstance](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj590758.aspx) cmdlet gets the Common Information Model (CIM) **instances** of a class from a CIM server …

Do not confuse methods of *Powershell* and *CimClass*  objects:

- The [Get-Member](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849928.aspx) cmdlet gets the members, the properties and methods, of **objects**. 
  **Output type**: `[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MemberDefinition]`
- The [Get-CimClass](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj590761.aspx) cmdlet gets a list of Common Information Model (CIM) classes in a specific namespace. 
  **Output type**: `[Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimClass]`

You are looking for something like

```
PS D:\PShell> (Get-CimClass -ClassName Win32_Process).CimClassMethods | 
    Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap

Name                    ReturnType Parameters 
----                    ---------- ---------- 
Create                      UInt32 {CommandLine, CurrentDirectory,
                                    ProcessStartupInformation, ProcessId}
Terminate                   UInt32 {Reason} 
GetOwner                    UInt32 {Domain, User} 
GetOwnerSid                 UInt32 {Sid} 
SetPriority                 UInt32 {Priority} 
AttachDebugger              UInt32 {} 
GetAvailableVirtualSize     UInt32 {AvailableVirtualSize}
```