# Powershell Invoke-Command does not return correct output

Tags: powershell, wmi, winrm

I'm trying to collect some registry values from remote server using StdRegProv class:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerHost -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock { Get-WmiObject -List -Namespace "root\default" | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "StdRegProv" } }
```

But it doesnt return methods for these class in output:

```
   NameSpace: ROOT\default

Name                                Methods              Properties                                                                       PSComputerName
----                                -------              ----------                                                                       --------------
StdRegProv
```

If i execute the command from ScriptBlock in machine locally, all works fine and output looks like these:

```
   NameSpace: ROOT\default

Name                                Methods              Properties                                                                                                                                                                                                
----                                -------              ----------                                                                                                                                                                                                
StdRegProv                          {CreateKey, Delet... {}
```

Some of other commands, like Get-Service, works ok and i can see the output. What is the problem with these one?
Remote machine is: Windows Server 2003 with installed .Net 3.5.1 and PowerShell 2.0

I thought, that StdRegProv class doesnt work in 2003 server, but it works ok locally

Comment: Windows Server 2003 and PowerShell 2.0? Plenty of risk there. https://www.netcraft.com/blog/millions-still-running-the-risk-with-windows-server-2003/

Comment: Same issue in Win 10 22H2 machine

Comment: That's the definition of returned serialized objects.  No methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an aside:

- The **CIM cmdlets** (e.g., `Get-CimInstance`) **superseded the WMI cmdlets** (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`) **in Windows PowerShell v3** (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), the modern cross-platform success to Windows PowerShell where all future effort will go, doesn't even *have* them anymore. Note that WMI still *underlies* the CIM cmdlets, however. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375); the **bottom section** below shows a **CIM solution**.
- Since you're running the - long obsolete - **Windows PowerShell **v2****, the **CIM cmdlets are *not* an option**.

---

You're **calling `Get-WmiObject` *via PowerShell [remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Remote)* (`Invoke-Command -ComputerName`)**, which for all but a handful of well-known types **involves a *loss of type fidelity***:

- Notably, instances of **most types are *emulated* with *method-less* `[psobject]` instances** that have a *static copy of all the (public) properties* of the original object - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67808632/45375) for details.

This explains why the result object is lacking methods.

You have two **options**:

- *Either*: **Call any methods *in the remotely executing script block***, where the [`Get-WmiObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-wmiobject?view=powershell-5.1) output object still has all its original identity.
  For instance, the following command calls the [`.GetStringValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/regprov/getstringvalue-method-in-class-stdregprov) method to retrieve the data stored in the `Path` value of registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\DefaultUserEnvironment` on the *remote* machine:

  ```
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerHost -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock { 
    (Get-WmiObject -List StdRegProv).GetStringValue(2147483650, 'SOFTWARE\DefaultUserEnvironment', 'Path')
  }
  ```
- *Or*: Use the **remoting provided by the *WMI* cmdlets**, in
  which case there is *no* loss of type fidelity; however, note that they use a ***different* remoting infrastructure than PowerShell, namely an obsolete *DCOM*-based one**, and may therefore need separate configuration; however, **as per your feedback, KB5004442 on *caller* machines actively *prevents* use of this infrastructure when targeting machines running *older* Windows versions**.

  ```
  # You can call methods such as `.GetStringValue()` directly
  # on the output object.
  (
    Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $ComputerHost -Credential $cred -List StdRegProv
  ).GetStringValue(2147483650, 'SOFTWARE\DefaultUserEnvironment', 'Path')
  ```

---

**CIM solution (PowerShell v3+)**

For the sake of completeness, here is the equivalent solution based on the CIM cmdlets:

```
$regProv = Get-CimClass StdRegProv -CimSession (New-CimSession -ComputerName $ComputerHost -Credential $cred)
$regProv | Invoke-CimMethod  -MethodName GetStringValue -Arguments @{ hDefKey = [Uint32] 2147483650; sSubKeyName = 'SOFTWARE\DefaultUserEnvironment'; sValueName = 'Path' }
```

However, you can use *just* an `Invoke-CimMethod` call in this case and specify the target class via the `-ClassName` parameter:

```
Invoke-CimMethod -ClassName StdRegProv -MethodName GetStringValue -Arguments @{ hDefKey = [Uint32] 2147483650; sSubKeyName = 'SOFTWARE\DefaultUserEnvironment'; sValueName = 'Path' }
```

- The [CIM cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets)' remoting uses the same infrastructure as PowerShell's remoting.
- While there is no loss in type fidelity, note that instances returned by CIM cmdlets do not have *.NET* methods that you can call directly; instead, CIM methods must be called via the [`Invoke-CimMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/invoke-cimmethod) cmdlet, as shown above.
- **Arguments** must be passed via the **`-Arguments` parameter**, which **requires a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) (dictionary) of *parameter name-value pairs.***

  - The parameter names can be gleaned from the `.Parameters` property of the `.CimClassMethods` property available on CIM class instances as returned by [`Get-CimClass`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-cimclass); for CIM *instances*, as returned by [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance), use `.CimClass.CimClassMethods`; e.g.:

    ```
    (Get-CimClass StdRegProv).CimClassMethods | 
      Where Name -eq GetStringValue |
      ForEach Parameters
    ```

    - This yields the following display output (note that the `out`-qualified parameter is the *output value*, returned as part of the *result object* - see below):

      ```
      Name        CimType Qualifiers ReferenceClassName
      ----        ------- ---------- ------------------
      hDefKey      UInt32 {ID, IN}
      sSubKeyName  String {ID, IN}
      sValueName   String {ID, in}
      sValue       String {ID, out}
      ```
    - Unfortunately, the parameter information does *not* indicate *optional* parameters or their default values; e.g., in the case of `GetStringValue()`, the `hDefKey` parameter is optional and defaults to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (`2147483650`)
  - **Caveat**:

    - Number-typed parameters must be bound by their *exact* type, hence the `[UInt32]` cast for the `hDefKey` parameter above.
- **Results** are reported as `[pscustomobject]` instances<sup>[1]</sup> with the following properties:

  - `.ReturnValue` ... the success status of the call; `0` indicates success.
  - `.PSComputerName` ... the name of the remote computer (if any) from which the result originates
  - `.<outParameterName>` ... the variably named property corresponding to the method's `out` parameter name, such as `.sValue` in the call above.

---

<sup>[1] These instances have an [ETS (Extended Type System)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6763) type name that reflects the class and method that was invoked, e.g. `Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimMethodResult#StdRegProv#GetStringValue`, such as reported by [`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member).</sup>

Comment: Unfortunately, WMI connection is not an option, coz main machine is windows server 2016 with last DCOM security update KB5004442. These update deny any WMI connections to\from non updated machines and ofc Windows Server 2003 doesn't have these update at all and i havent found workaround to it. These is the main reason why i have to use WinRM here.

Regarding "Either" part. Could you please give some example of what u mean, coz it's not clear for me to be honest

Comment: Understood, @user21072039; re the "Either" part: please see my update.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @user21072039; my pleasure.